# Why doesn't my function work with spaces? (cd, dirname)

Tags: shell, function, variable, whitespace

I have had this function I use it very often and it works fine.

Here it is:

```
cdx () { cd `dirname $1` ; }
```

However, this does not work with spaces. When I use it like this for example

```
cdx ~/desktop/folder/file\ file
```

It returns

```
usage: dirname path
```

But what I am passing is, essentially `dirname path`. So what am I supposed to do to fix this? (It also does the same thing when there are spaces in a folder names)

My first thought was using quotes, like  `cdX "directory\ whatever"` but it did not work either.

Comment: [Leaving a command substitution (`\`...\``) or variable unquoted is the split+glob operator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346). You don't want to do that here. `cdx() { cd -- "$(dirname -- "$1")"; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply write `$i`, spaces will turn your variable content in multiple arguments. If you want to preserve spaces you have to quote things.

For your example you probably want:

```
cdx () { cd -- "$(dirname -- "$1")" ; }
```

And remember *always* quote your variables.

Comment: Why always quote variables? You mean i should edit all my function to be "$1" "$2" whatever instead of $1, $2?

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise you will run into problems when facing paths containing spaces.

Comment: Isn't this okay? `cdX () { cd "$(dirname "$1")" ; }`

Comment: Yes, that is fine. - Unless your directory happens to start with a dash. Then `cd` thinks you are giving options instead of an actual path. Adding `--` will enforce the argument to be interpreted as an actual pathname.